# Question about clojure namespaces and macros

Tags: macros, clojure

Suppose I've got a bunch of namespaces (apple, banana, orange). In these namespaces I use the `eat` macro, which calls (not "generates", **calls**) the `peel` function. The `peel` function is different for each fruit, but the macros are identical, and fairly big, so I'd like to create a `fruit` namespace that contains the `eat` macro. But when I call the `eat` macro from the `apple` namespace, the `eat` macro should call the `apple/peel` function.

To illustrate (but this doesn't work):

```
(ns fruit)
(defmacro eat [] (peel))

(ns apple)
(defn peel [] (prn "peeled apple"))
(fruit/eat)

(ns banana)
(defn peel [] (prn "peeled banana"))
(fruit/eat)
```

To emphasize, this means that the peel function should be called when, and only when, the macro is expanded, as in this example.

```
(ns apple)
(defn peel [] (prn "peeled apple"))
(defmacro eat [] (peel))
(macroexpand-1 '(eat))
```

So, any ideas on how to combine macros and polymorphism?

Answer (score 7):

What you're describing is not polymorphism but what is called *local capture*.  You want the *eat* macro to "capture" the local definition of *peel*.

This is considered bad style in most Lisps, especially Clojure, as it can lead to subtle and unpredictable bugs.

A better solution is to pass the correct *peel* to the *eat* macro when you call it:

```
(ns fruit)
(defmacro eat [peeler] `(~peeler))

(ns apple)
(defn peel [] (prn "Peeled an apple"))
(fruit/eat peel)
```

If you really want to do local capture, you can force it with a ~' (unquote-quote) in the macro:

```
(ns fruit)
(defmacro eat [] `(~'peel))
```

Comment: This is not quite what I meant. I'd like the `peel` function to be called on expand time. I've clarified the question.

Comment: I understand, will provide another answer.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the edited question, this is slightly different from local capture, because you're not using *peel* in the macroexpansion, but rather in the execution of the macro itself.

That's difficult because macros do not evaluate their arguments.  Even if you pass *peel* as an argument to *eat*, within the body of the macro it's just a symbol, not a callable function.

The only way to do what you want (without using *eval*) is to resolve the symbol at compile time:

```
(defmacro eat []
   ((var-get (resolve 'peel)))
   ... return the expansion of "eat" ...)
```

The *resolve* function takes a symbol and returns the Var it is mapped to in the current namespace.  Once you have the Var, you can retrieve the actual function (the Var's value) with *var-get*.  The extra set of parentheses calls that function.

Needless to say, this is a very unusual design and might warrant rethinking.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defmacro eat [] ((var-get (resolve 'peel))))
```

Note that you are abusing namespaces, though.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Sorry. I alread posted the following. But you're saying "calls, not generates" the peel function. So what I've written is probably not what you want although it seems it would get the intended result.

Simply quoting `(peel)` worked for me.

```
(ns fruit)
(defmacro eat [] '(peel))

(ns apple)
(defn peel [] (prn "peeled apple"))
(fruit/eat)

(ns banana)
(defn peel [] (prn "peeled banana"))
(fruit/eat)
```

Comment: Thank you, but indeed not what I meant. It does get the desired result here, but not in my actual use case.